# Object detection model's performance jumping up and down

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I am training a model to detect buildings from satellite images in rural Africa. For labels, I use OpenStreetMap geometries. I use the Tensorflow Object Detection API and SSD Inception V2 as a model and I use the default config file. I trained separate models on two different datasets (in different geographical regions). In one area, the model behaves like I would expect:

[image: karonga]

When training the model in the other area, however, it's performance jumps up and down:
[image]

Note that I use the exact same model, configuration, batch size, the training area is of the same size, etc. In the second case, the model's prediction change extremely rapidly and I am not able to see why. For example, here is a comparison of the predictions the model makes at 107k and 108k global steps (i.e. I'd expect the predictions to be similar):

[image]

I am quite new to deep learning and cannot understand why this might happen.  It might be something simple that I am overlooking. I've checked the labels and they are ok. Also, I thought that it could be a bad batch that in every epoch turns the training in the wrong direction but this is not the case - the performance drops like that for up to several epochs.

I would be very grateful for any tips where to look, etc. I am using TF 1.14.

Let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: try smaller step size, play with learning rate. Also, consider the fact that data of two geographical places can be different and you may have a large step size because of which gradient descent take big jumps and never reached the absolute minimum or suitable local minimum.